# Running into c++ virtual template function issue due to interface based programming

Tags: c++, api-design, googlemock

We are designing a new system where we have created interfaces for most of our classes so that we can create mocks (google mocks) for them for unit testing. As a result, all the functions are virtual but the issue is that I am often running into template virtual function issue due to this. I have seen some examples on how to do multi dispatch but they all seem to be using some variation of templates, it doesn't seem straightforward. So does it mean that my entire codebase will now end up with templates making it difficult to read/use and debug?

Or am I not designing good interfaces. Here is a simple example where I am writing an interface for a message queue.

```
Class IMessageQueue {

   Public:

    Virtual int send(const T & value);  // I can't do this but this is exactly what I want to do, as send should be able to send any type 

};

Class MessageQueue : public IMessageQueue {
      Public:

       Virtual int send(const T & value) { ... }
};

Class MockMQ : public IMessageQueue {
      Public: 
         Virtual int send(const T & value) {
               // mock implementation
          }
};
```

How do I get around this problem? This is just one example but I run into lots of these type of issues due to interface based programming.

Comment: You could probably get around them by making them not virtual and having a helper function that determines the type by dynamic_cast and then calls the templated member function of that specific type. I don't know how ugly and maintanable it would end up in your specific case, also I have never tried that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you need your IMessageQueue to dispatch specific unknown type or any type. That's not the same thing.

A specific unknown type can be managed by

```
template<typename T>
class IMessageQueue {
public:
  virtual int send(const T& value);
}
```

So that you can have your `IMessageQueue<MyMessage>` and `IMessageQueue<OtherMessage>`.

If, instead, you need to be able to send any type with the same type of message queue then your option is to declare a specific interface common to all messages as in

```
class Message
{
protected:
  Message() : { .. }
};

class MyMessage : public Message
{
..
};

class MessageQueue
{
public:
  void send(const Message& message);
};
```

Comment: Thank Jack. If IMesageQueue is a template class then send cannot be virtual anymore, no? I like the second solution better, but does it mean that I need to create a new message type subclass every time I need to send a new type of data? I want to create a library and expose it so I won't have flexibility to change library often. We can probably make message as template but I think we will be back to same problem again as IMessage send() method will take Mesage<T> and this will again not allow us to make send as virtual.